# What are the applications of normalization in math

Tags: probability, measure-theory

I know what a normalization of numbers mean in probability. As far as I know;
If a=3, b=2,c=1: Then nomalized value of a is 3/(1+2+3), b is 2/(1+2+3) & c is 1/(1+2+3).

But I dont know why do we take normalization and what are some of the applications of it.

Thanks some enlightment is appreciated.

Comment: A typical use is: $c-\sum w_i x_i = \sum w_i(c-x_i)$, which works only if the weights $w_i$ add up to one. Just yesterday I used normalization of weights in this answer: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/154254/frechet-mean-between-points-in-mathbbr3/154300#154300

Comment: so does it somewhat mean to calculate where actually a particular entity stands in a contest? like say how much fraction of a pie does someone take out of a whole.